# Add fixed margins to a responsive grid

Tags: html, css

Here's a responsive grid I've made. I want to add 10px margin around all elements. 
And I need these margins to be the same width all the time.
But applying margins broke the responsive aspect of the grid. I need margins to "squeeze" the div not to "push" it.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  background: #EBEBEB;
}

.ideas__gallery__h3 {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}

.one {
  width: 33.3333333333333333%;
  height: 310px;
  background: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  width: 33.3333333333333333%;
  height: 310px;
  background: lightpink;
  float: left;
}

.three {
  width: 33.3333333333333333%;
  height: 310px;
  background: lightyellow;
  float: left;
}

.four {
  width: 33.3333333333333333%;
  height: 310px;
  background: lightcyan;
  float: left;
}

.five {
  width: 66.6666666666666666%;
  height: 310px;
  background: lightgreen;
  float: left;
}

.six {
  width: 66.6666666666666666%;
  height: 310px;
  background: lightskyblue;
  float: left;
}

.seven {
  width: 33.3333333333333333%;
  height: 310px;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ideas__gallery">
    <h3 class="ideas__gallery__h3">Headline</h3>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="four"></div>
    <div class="five"></div>
    <div class="six"></div>
    <div class="seven"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `calc` to remove the `margin` from the `width`. This will mean the `margin` will no longer make the `div`s exceed the `width` of the container which is forcing them onto a new line.

The following changes are required:

- Add a new rule `.ideas__gallery div` with `margin: 10px;`. This will add the `margin` to all the child `div`s of `.ideas__gallery`
- Modify the `width` of each of the `div`s to use `calc` to remove the `margin` from the calculated `width`

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  background: #EBEBEB;
}

.ideas__gallery__h3 {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}

.ideas__gallery div {
  margin: 10px;
}

.one {
  width: calc(33.3333333333333333% - 20px);
  height: 310px;
  background: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  width: calc(33.3333333333333333% - 20px);
  height: 310px;
  background: lightpink;
  float: left;
}

.three {
  width: calc(33.3333333333333333% - 20px);
  height: 310px;
  background: lightyellow;
  float: left;
}

.four {
  width: calc(33.3333333333333333% - 20px);
  height: 310px;
  background: lightcyan;
  float: left;
}

.five {
  width: calc(66.6666666666666666% - 20px);
  height: 310px;
  background: lightgreen;
  float: left;
}

.six {
  width: calc(66.6666666666666666% - 20px);
  height: 310px;
  background: lightskyblue;
  float: left;
}

.seven {
  width: calc(33.3333333333333333% - 20px);
  height: 310px;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ideas__gallery">
    <h3 class="ideas__gallery__h3">Headline</h3>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
    <div class="four"></div>
    <div class="five"></div>
    <div class="six"></div>
    <div class="seven"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You ca use `css calc`. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/7gpt6ufd/)

```
.one, .two, .three
{
    margin: 10px;
    width:calc(33.3333333333333333% - 20px);
}
```